# function onchange/click for laravel form::checkbox?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, laravel-8

So, I'm trying to have some disabled inputs that enable whenever you check the checkbox on top of it, but I can't seem to find how

```
<ul class="list-unstyled">
    @foreach ($almacenes as $almacen)
        <li class="list-group-item"> 
            <label>
                {!! Form::checkbox('almacenes_id[]', $almacen->id,null) !!}
                {{ $almacen->id }} - {{ $almacen->nom_alm }}
            </label>                    
                <input type="number" name="available[]" id="available[]" class="form-control" value="0" disabled>
        </li>
    @endforeach
</ul>
```

My function is:

```
<script>
    function almacenes_id(){   
          if (document.getElementById("almacenes_id").checked)
          document.getElementById('disponible').disabled = false;
              
          else
          document.getElementById('disponible').disabled = true;
                    
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    <ul class="list-unstyled">
        @php
        $i = 0;
        @endphp
        @foreach ($almacenes as $almacen)
            <li class="list-group-item"> 
                <label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="almacenes_id[]" id="almacenes_id{{$i}}" class="form-control" onchange="getChecked{{$i}}()">                
 {{ $almacen->id }} - {{ $almacen->nom_alm }}
                </label>                    
                    <input type="number" name="available[]" id="available{{$i}}" class="form-control" value="0" disabled>
            </li>
        </ul>

<script>
function getChecked{{$i}}() {
    const checkBox = document.getElementById("almacenes_id{{$i}}").checked;
      
      if (checkBox !== true) 
      {        
       document.getElementById('available{{$i}}').disabled = true;        
      } else if (checkBox === true) 
      {        
        document.getElementById('available{{$i}}').disabled = false;       
      }
}                              
</script>
@php
$i++;
@endphp
@endforeach
```

Comment: so, now it only works for the last input and checkbox

Comment: Check now please.